# Unable to place marker in google map after converting string to double

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers

I got latitude and longitude values from my db with type string because i am using json. Now i converted that string value into double for placing marker in map. If i toast the string value i am getting toast message but after converting into double i am not getting the marker.

```
    String lati = p.getLati();
    String longi = p.getLongi();

    // Loading map
    initilizeMap();

    double l1 = Double.parseDouble(lati);
    double latitude = l1;
    double l2 = Double.parseDouble(longi);
    double longitude = l2;
    // create marker
    // Log.e(name, place);
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");

    // adding marker
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lati, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), longi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

source code

```
 GoogleMap map = ... // get a map.
// Add a marker at San Francisco.
 Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
 .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))// your latitude, longitude
 .title("San Francisco")
 .snippet("Population: 776733"));
```

More details refer this

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker

Comment: I am  getting the values from database

Comment: thats not problem.get value from database and pass in method new LatLng( your latitude, longitude)